# WCF windows service not reading from MSMQ

Tags: windows, wcf, service, msmq

I have a WCF service hosted as a windows service.

The WCF service reads from an MSMQ and does some processing.

It is running fine when installed locally on my windows 7 machine and reads properly from a public queue on my machine and does some action.

However when the service and the public queue is set up on a Windows 2008 server, the public queue has entries, but the WCF service is not picking it up.

Made sure all features are turned on the server machine as it is on my windows 7 machine and still no luck.

Not sure if there are any settings that I need to enable on the server machine for the WCF service to read from the queue.

Comment: What creditials is the windows service running under on the server?  It might not have permission to access the queue.

Comment: We have set up an account that the service is running under and it has full permissions on the concerned queue. The best part is I am able to point my local service code against this remote queue and I am able to process the queue entries.... So not quite sure what the issue is as to why the service is running and not able to pick the entries....

Comment: Did you clone the server from one with MSMQ already on it?